# Perl: search index of element using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that contains several columns separated with `\t`, and I want to get the position (index) of some columns by using regular expressions to specify the name of header of columns.
Here is my code, but I can't search using regular expressions:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
my %dic;
my %index;
while(<>) {
    my @array2 = split(/\t/, $_);
    @index{@array2} = (0..$#array2);

    my $column13= $index{"name13"};// Here I want to search  using regex
    my $column17= $index{"name17"};// Here I want to search  using regex
    my $column21= $index{"name21"};// Here I want to search  using regex
    my $column34= $index{"name32"};// Here I want to search  using regex
    my $column43= $index{"name43"};// Here I want to search  using regex

    print $array2[$column13]$.",".$array2[$column17].",".$array2[$column21].
          ",".$array2[$column34].",".$array2[$column43]."\n"; 
}
```

For example the value of `$columns13` should be 12 (position 12) and:

```
 $column17 = 16
 $column21 = 20
 $column34 = 33
 $column43 = 42
```

My input is a file that contains several columns separated with `\t`:

```
name1   name2   name3...    name85
1   2   3       4   ....     765
6   5   9       67  ....      8768
87  787 767     7687 ......   8768
```

My output should contains only the colums that have been searched:

```
name13  name17  name21...   name43
    876 76  87      4  .... 87687
   787  987 9       67  ...  87686
    53  765 767     7687 .... 8686
```

Comment: Perhaps you should give an example of what you are trying to do, with input and expected output.

Comment: Ok I will add example in my question thanks

Comment: Your print statement `print $array2[$column13].","....` can be written much simpler with an array slice and join: `print join(",", @array2[$column13, $column17, ...]), "\n";`

Comment: ok Thanks.
I added the input and output in my question

Comment: I want only search specified name using regex in headr of columns if match then it should give my the position of this column

Comment: You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write. Without those in place there is little point in using `my`.

Comment: Does your program work correctly as it is? Where is the list of column headers coming from?

Comment: yes It works I can get the position by specifying the name exactely. but i want to use regex to specify the name begin with ex:(/^abc/). and there is no list of headers i have a file that containe several line and each line sepearated with a tab \t and in the first line I have the name of headers

Comment: So you want to select a set of columns based on a single regex? Where does that regex come from? Do you want to hard-code it into your program? Should your output include the header line?

Comment: Yes my output should have headers. concerning regex , no every regex  should return to my the position of one column.

Comment: because the name of headers is not fixed it can have other letter added, that is why I have to use regex to specify the start of name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specification is rather sloppy, but I think this will do as you ask. It takes the first non-blank line from the input as the header line, and creates a list of corresponding indices in `@indices`. The corresponding columns from each subsequent are printed to STDOUT.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @selection = qw(
    name1
    name3
    name85
);

my @indices;

while (<>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;

  unless (@indices) {
    @indices = grep {
      my $i = $_;
      grep { $fields[$i] =~ /$_/ } @selection;
    } 0 .. $#fields;
  }

  print join("\t", @fields[@indices]), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't have an array that contains the header, the header is the first line in the file who I give as argument

Comment: And what is @selection please?

Comment: I can't help you if you won't answer where your list of wanted column headers comes from.

Comment: I have an input file, the first line is considered as headers, after headers comes others lines that contains values, and I execute my code it works i have any other inputs, I want to search the position of columns by specifyin the name of a header

Comment: Okay, so if you have no other inputs then there is no way to specify the names of the headers.

Comment: @index{@array2} = (0..$#array2);
my $column13= $index{"name13"}; this command allows to me to get the position of name13. but i want to specify "name13" using regex

Comment: So you want to *hard code* the patterns into your program?

Comment: Okay. You haven't described what the patterns would look like, so I used your original column names in my solution. Please try using regular expressions instead.

Comment: I tried to put the regex /^name/ instead of  name1 in @selection ... but doesn't work

Comment: The regex pattern doesn't include the slashes

Comment: Yes it works! thank you very match! please and if I have some columns that have same name? what can i do to get the first occurence?

Comment: @ImiiIik: Stack Overflow is an archive of more or less ordinary programming problems, and a resource for everyone. Your question is already too specific to have much application elsewhere. To request more information on top of that goes into the realm of asking for free programming effort. Sometimes I will do even that but, since you clearly have almost no understanding of Perl, I am sure that you will be asking more questions as soon as you need to make any changes. Please demonstrate some knowledge of Perl before you ask for any more help.

Comment: Ok Thanks I'm not developer I want just automate a task,

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, well the way it works is that you're supposed to *pay for a developer* to do the work for you. I don't know what you do for a living, but I doubt if you do it for free?